Is there a way to synchonize access to a singleton in C#?
I'm running into a situation while trying to run unit tests against a singleton.  I'm using a singleton to manage a single HttpClient that my application can use to make Http Requests. I know that there are other ways to do this, but this is the approach that I'm working with at the moment.
During normal operation there's no problem with this approach, since the HttpClient object is created once and never changes for the life of the application.  The problem comes in when I try to run unit tests, as I'm creating multiple HttpClients so I can mock their responses.
Here's basically what my singleton class looks like (this is not the actual code, just an example to show the basic idea).
internal sealed class MySingleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<MySingleton> _ instance = new Lazy<MySingleton>(() => new MySingleton());

    public static MySingleton Instance => _instance.Value;

    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    internal HttpClient HttpClient
    {
        get => _httpClient;
        set //This is provided for testing, so I can mock the HttpMessageHandler
        {
            _httpClient = value;
        }
    }

    private MySingleton()
    {
        SocketsHttpHandler
            handler = new SocketsHttpHandler
            {
                PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
            };
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    }

    internal async Task<bool> SendRequest()
    {
        //Uses the HttpClient to send a request.
        return true;
    }
}

With this in place, whenever my app needs to send an Http request it can just call await MySingleton.Instance.Send(). This works just fine in normal operation.
The problem comes in when I run unit tests, since they manipulate the HttpClient and run in parallel. Currently I'm forcing the tests to run synchronously, but that's not an ideal solution.  Here's an idea of what my tests look like.
public class Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task This_Is_A_Test()
    {
        string
            jsonText = """
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "name" : "testing",
                "value" : 23
            }
            """;
        HttpMessageHandler
            httpMessageHandler = new MockHttpMessageHandler(jsonText, System.Net.HttpStatus.Created);
        MySingleton.Instance.HttpClient = new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler);

        bool
            result = await MySingleton.Instance.SendRequest();
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
}

The MockHttpMessageHandler object is just a class I wrote that extends the HttpMessageHandler class, so I can manipulate the response from the HttpClient.
As you can see from the test code, I'm replacing the HttpClient in the singleton with one that will return the data that I want.  This has the side-effect of causing tests to fail, when they're run in parallel.
I'm wondering if there's a way to synchronize access to the instance of the singleton, so that it can only be used by one thread at at time. Basically a thread would grab the singleton, use it for what it needed, then release it back to be used by another thread.
Maybe my approach here is totally wrong, in which case I'm open to suggestions. Though I'd really like to know if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do. I've tried to google the answer, but only came up with was to synchronize the creation of the instance (which Lazy already handles). I've even tried AI, though that wasn't any more helpful.

https://flurl.dev/docs/testable-http/ might make things easier, generally

@flackoverstow That looks like it could be quite useful, but I'm currently trying to reduce the use of 3rd party packages.

ThreadLocal / AsyncLocal as a hack maybe? The correct solution of course it to not use singletons -- they're famously annoying when it comes to unit tests

You should be able to configure the problematic tests to run sequentially, or ensure all tests take a lock to force them to run sequentially. But the correct solution is to avoid the singleton in the first place.

@JonasH I'm currently running all the tests sequentially to avoid the issue.  I'd like to avoid using the singleton pattern, but I'm struggling to find a solution that doesn't rely on dependency injection, 3rd party packages, and avoids all the pitfalls associated with using HttpClient.  If you could suggest a better approach I'd really appreciate it, as I'm having trouble finding alternative solutions.

My suggestion would be to dependency injection container. You can use dependency injection without a 3rd party library, but I would just use a DI container library since it tend to make issues like this so much simpler. I can't really understand why you prefer singletons to these patterns.

@JonasH I didn't use DI, because I'm not creating a web project.  The project is going to be a library, that I'll be using in other projects.  As it is now the project works just fine, and only has a limitation that the unit tests cannot be run in parallel. I'm trying to reduce the number of 3rd party packages; especially ones I've never used, because I don't have the time to evaluate new packages (security, stability, and other concerns).

Dependency injection works perfectly well in libraries. You may not want to enforce any specific dependency injection container library if you are writing a library, but you can still take the httpClient as a constructor parameter and let the user of your library worry about how it is created. DI container libraries, like Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection also work perfectly well in non-web applications.

Arguably, not using singletons is even more important in a library, since threadsafety is a potential problem with singletons, and will make your library more difficult to use correctly. It is generally assumed that static properties/methods are threadsafe unless otherwise documented.

Write an extension method for users to configure the DI services your library offers. Then use DI singletons, not language pattern singletons.

You could pretty easily synchronize access. One way would be to replace the HttpClient property with methods that do the synchronization. Something like the below.
// this code replaces the HttpClient property
private HttpClient _httpClient;
private static object lockObj = new object();

// Attempts to acquire the object.
// If it can't, it returns null.
public static HttpClient TryGet()
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj))
       return HttpClient;
    return null;
}

// Attempts to acquire the object.
// Blocks until it can.
public static HttpClient Get()
{
    Monitor.Enter(lockObj);
    return HttpClient;
}

// Releases the previously-acquired object
public static Release()
{
    Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
}

To use it you call Get or TryGet to acquire exclusive access to the HttpClient. When you're finished with it, call Release. Something like:
var client = MySingleton.Get();
try
{
    // do whatever you need to do with client
}
finally
{
    MySingleton.Release();
}

The standard cautions apply. If the thread that acquires the resource terminates without releasing it, you might end up with a problem. I honestly don't know how Monitor handles abandonment.
